# Android: Firebase Dynamic Links open browser first before opening app

Tags: android, firebase, dynamic, hyperlink

I'm having an issue with Firebase Deep Links on Android.
I have 3 Firebase dynamic links, which are for 3 build flavors of one app, they are like this:

https://my_subdomain.page.link?link=https://my_subdomain.page.link/**app1**?param1=aaa&param2=bbb&apn=**app1_package_name**

https://my_subdomain.page.link?link=https://my_subdomain.page.link/**app2**?param1=aaa&param2=bbb&apn=**app2_package_name**

https://my_subdomain.page.link?link=https://my_subdomain.page.link/**app3**?param1=aaa&param2=bbb&apn=**app3_package_name**

- Now what I want when I click on those links is: my corresponding apps
  will open directly.
- But the actual result is: the links redirect me to the browser first,
  then after about 1 second, open the app.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.

1. Create 3 different URL prefixes on Firebase: subdomain1.page.link, subdomain2.page.link, subdomain3.page.link.
2. Declare a new intent filter in AndroidManifest, which looks like this:
3. Also remember to declare a variable named "app_subdomain" with respective values (subdomain1, subdomain2, subdomain3) for each app in build.gradle. For example:

   **manifestPlaceholders["app_subdomain"] = "subdomain1"**
4. Type yourself these 3 links and use the parameters the way you like:

https://subdomain1.page.link?link=https://my_subdomain.page.link?param1=aaa&param2=bbb&apn=app1_package_name

https://subdomain2.page.link?link=https://my_subdomain.page.link?param1=aaa&param2=bbb&apn=app2_package_name

https://subdomain3.page.link?link=https://my_subdomain.page.link/?param1=aaa&param2=bbb&apn=app3_package_name

That should do it!